# Golang use interfaces for structs with no getter

Tags: go

I work on a Golang project that inherits **hundreds** of structs from auto-generated code from an OpenAPI specification. These structs all have common fields and I want to create a generic function that would work on each of them.

I tried using an interface, but the generic function needs access
to some fields that are not exposed by any functions.

Here is a minimal example :

```
package main

import "fmt"

type StructInterface interface {
    getA() string
}

type Struct_1 struct {
    A string
    B string 
}

func (s Struct_1) getA() string {
    return s.A
}

type Struct_2 struct {
    A string
    B string
    C string
}

func (s Struct_2) getA() string {
    return s.A
}

// Each struct have A and B attributes that are used in genericFunction()
// But there is no Getter for B attribute
func genericFunction(myStruct StructInterface) {
    fmt.Printf("Here is A value : %v\n", myStruct.getA())
    fmt.Printf("Here is B value : %v\n", myStruct.B)  // <-- Won't work
}

func main() {
    genericFunction(Struct_1{A: "AAA", B: "BBB"})
    genericFunction(Struct_2{A: "AAA", B: "BBB", C: "CCC"})
}
```

What would be a clean way to do that ? (without having to add hundreds of identical `getB()` methods)

Comment: Add a method `GetB()` to `StructInterface`

Comment: The thing is that I can't add a getter to my structs. They come from code that has been generated from an  OpenAPI specification and I can't edit them

Comment: @Nakeuh: you can either add a getter to the interface, or you assert a specific type to the value. You can't access struct fields through an interface.